# Installer cannot find language file, but it does exist

Tags: plugin, language

I regularly get an error similar to this:

> JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist
>   /*******/public_html/dev/tmp/install_5e834b10a9f88/en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.ini

Here is my XML

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

I check and I see both files exist.  I copy and paste the files names to make sure there are no errors.  The .sys file seems to load correctly.  Here is the name copied and pasted:

> en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.ini

The location is the same as the .sys version which is:

> language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.ini

This happens a lot and I find it really hard to understand what the issue is.  The file exists, and when I check my zip file it is there.  Does anyone have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong as this happens a lot and I haven't got a very reliable methodology to check for errors other than checking spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file structure doesn't match the manifest file. Currently the manifest looks for language files in the root directory of your package.

You can add `folder` attribute with path to language files to `<languages>` tag:

```
<languages folder="language/en-GB">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Or prepend the path to each `<language>` tag:

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_kou_address_mapper.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Or move language files to root directory.

Comment: Ah ha!  That's amazing.  It's been over a year I've been having similar problems.  Why does the .sys version work?  I can't believe I have got any of my plugins/modules working without this knowledge!  Thanks so much

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `.sys` file does not get installed either but it does get loaded from temporary folder during installation, provided the file structure follows a certain convention (i.e. `language/en-GB`).

Comment: Ah, I thought the convention carried through.  I must have read that somewhere.  Thank you.